# Relative layout on a TabHost?

Tags: android

I have an Android UI issue that I am not quite sure how to solve.  I have a tabhost with a couple of different items on it.  In one case, the fields added to a scrollView (which is on one of the tabs) will be added dynamically. I have a button at the bottom of the screen, using a relative layout.  The problem is that the scrollview (and the other tab's linear layout) extend beyond the bottom button.  This results in the final field on the screen being unviewable, as it is hidden by the button.  Here is a screenshot of the issue as well as the xml for my layouts. Any help is greatly appreciated.[image]

**The main layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_nologo" >

<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp" >

<TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<View android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dip"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<include layout="@layout/mc_message_send_tab_details"/>

<!-- Scrollview for message data -->
<ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/formTab">

<!-- Form fields are automatically 
    created in McMessageViewActivity. -->
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/formLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <View android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dip"/>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">      
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
    <Button android:text="Send" 
        android:id="@+id/btnSend" android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="0px"/>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

</TabHost>
```

**The additional Tab Layout:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/detailsTab">

    <TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:stretchColumns="1">

        <View android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dip"/>

       <TableRow>
           <TextView
               android:text="Unit #"
               android:textStyle="bold"
               android:gravity="right"
               android:padding="3dip" />
           <Spinner android:id="@+id/unitNumber"
               android:text=""
               android:padding="3dip"
               android:layout_marginRight="2sp"/>
       </TableRow>
       <TableRow>
           <TextView
               android:text="User ID"
               android:textStyle="bold"
               android:gravity="right"
               android:padding="3dip" />
           <EditText android:id="@+id/userId"
               android:text=""
               android:padding="3dip"
               android:layout_marginRight="2sp" />
       </TableRow>
       <TableRow>
           <TextView
               android:text="Form #"
               android:textStyle="bold"
               android:gravity="right"
               android:padding="3dip" />
           <Spinner android:id="@+id/formNumber"
               android:text=""
               android:padding="3dip"
               android:layout_marginRight="2sp" />
       </TableRow>
       <TableRow>
           <TextView
               android:text="Sending status"
               android:textStyle="bold"
               android:gravity="right"
               android:padding="3dip" />
           <EditText android:id="@+id/sendingStatus"
               android:text=""
               android:padding="3dip"
               android:layout_marginRight="2sp"/>
       </TableRow>
       <TableRow>
           <TextView
               android:text="Delivery priority"
               android:textStyle="bold"
               android:gravity="right"
               android:padding="3dip" />
           <EditText android:id="@+id/priority"
               android:text=""
               android:padding="3dip"
               android:layout_marginRight="2sp"/>
       </TableRow>
       <TableRow>
           <TextView
               android:text="Request reply"
               android:textStyle="bold"
               android:gravity="right"
               android:padding="3dip" />
           <CheckBox android:id="@+id/requestReply"
               android:padding="3dip"
               android:layout_marginRight="2sp" />
       </TableRow>
       <TableRow>
           <TextView
               android:text="Receipt conf"
               android:textStyle="bold"
               android:gravity="right"
               android:padding="3dip" />
           <CheckBox android:id="@+id/receiptConfirmation"
               android:padding="3dip"
               android:layout_marginRight="2sp" />
       </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>   

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your main problem is due to the fact that TabHost extends FrameLayout. That's why you used the last RelativeLayout on the main Layout. You tried to cheat and you lost... :)

What you have to do is it put a unique view (eg. a RelativeLayout) into the TabHost and then place all other view inside.

Something like the following (I had to remove some `<includes />` and background to get it work on my computer) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
        <View
            android:id="@+id/separator"
            android:layout_below="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dip" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/separator"
            android:layout_above="@+id/btnSend"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <!-- Scrollview for message data -->
            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/formTab">
                <!--
                    Form fields are automatically created in
                    McMessageViewActivity.
                -->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/formLayout"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <View
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="5dip" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </FrameLayout>
        <!--  Unnecessary      <LinearLayout-->
        <!--            android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
        <!--            android:layout_width="fill_parent"-->
        <!--            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">-->
        <Button
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="Send"
            android:id="@+id/btnSend"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
        <!--        </LinearLayout>-->
    </RelativeLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Comment: You just became my hero.  Thank you!

Comment: There's a typo at line 17.